# SAM CLI and Quarkus: /var/task/bootstrap: no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, quarkus, aws-sam-cli

When I try to use SAM cli to invoke my quarkus native function locally as per the [tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda) it fails to run with bellow error `no such file or directory` for  `/var/task/bootstrap`. Function.zip does exist and contain bootstrap, Anyone have any ideas how to solve?

OS: Ubuntu 18 (on VirtualBox)

```
walter@ubuntu18 brialambda/target $ sam local invoke --template sam.native.yaml --event ../payload.json
Invoking not.used.in.provided.runtime (provided)
Decompressing /home/walter/workspace/walterlambda/target/function.zip
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-provided:rapid-1.35.0-x86_64.

Mounting /tmp/tmp41trke88 as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: ee5e27d8-4bb7-4e0a-8873-f92c48459993 Version: $LATEST
time="2021-11-09T14:15:38.302" level=error msg="Init failed" InvokeID= error="fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: no such file or directory"
Function 'WalterlambdaNative' timed out after 15 seconds
```

Comment: the initial proposed solution below (now deleted) was incorrect, unable to reproduce the fix.

still unable to fix above

Comment: If I step back from above and try to just invoke on AWS rather than SAM local I get the below error. i think this is the real issue...
`target/manage.sh native invoke`

`Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
{"errorMessage":"RequestId: 2051de27-3cfa-408b-99e0-cec59025ffb1 Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]","errorType":"Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint"}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, make your executable binary is named `bootstrap` if you are using `PROVIDED_AL` runtime for golang.

e.g. `go build -o .bin/bootstrap ./lambda/main.go`

Answer (score -1):

I've seen that issue when people followed the non-native build process (https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda#build-and-deploy) but deployed as native. It is important to do the native build (https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda#deploy-to-aws-lambda-custom-native-runtime) by calling e.g.

```
./mvnw package -Dnative
```

or

```
./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native
```

There are two other related posts as well:

- [Unable to Invoke Quarkus Functions Natively in an AWS Lambda function with MacOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988221/unable-to-invoke-quarkus-functions-natively-in-an-aws-lambda-function-with-macos)
- [Micronaut GraalVM Native Image: Lambda fails with an error "Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749387/micronaut-graalvm-native-image-lambda-fails-with-an-error-error-fork-exec-va)