# Invoking Quarkus Lambda function with MacOS M1 on a native build

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, quarkus-native

I've been trying to invoke AWS Lambda functions (Quarkus) locally using AWS SAM CLI.

```bash
sam local invoke --template target/sam.native.yaml --event payload.json
```

Which is using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-provided).

Here is the relevant (hopefully) information.

File `Dockerfile.graalbase`

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:ol8-java11-22.2.0 AS build
RUN gu install native-image

WORKDIR /project
VOLUME ["/project"]
ENTRYPOINT ["native-image"]
```

Built with:

```bash
docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.graalbase -t graalbase
```

Packaging:

```bash
mvn clean package -Dquarkus.package.type=native \
                  -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true \
                  -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=graalbase
```

This is what I get:

```bash
Mounting /private/var/folders/zm/0m9j6d_514q7sjpkgg6_7lzr0000gq/T/tmptq9x6jc9 as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 3cf00931-c409-426d-b568-98b5a2402da8 Version: $LATEST
16 Sep 2022 15:11:25,289 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: no such file or directory InvokeID=
```

Visiting the running container, this is the actual problem:

```bash
# The file does exist
ls -la /var/task/bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 115716600 Sep 16 15:12 /var/task/bootstrap

# Executing it results in
exec /var/task/bootstrap
/var/task/bootstrap: /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Additional args:

```bash
-H:+RemoveSaturatedTypeFlows,\
-H:+PrintAnalysisStatistics
```

- My bet was inspired by [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16225#issuecomment-999549585) discussion.
- The approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63988221/2251135) leads to the build getting stuck.

**UPDATED**

Quoting [Clement Escoffier](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images/issues/210#issuecomment-1261254470):

> Yes, you got an ARM 64 container, not a Linux 64 container.
> Cross-compilation is not supported by graalvm.
>
> I'm working on a way to enable it using qemu, but I'm only at the
> beginning of the journey.

In short, support is on the way ;)

Comment: You can build for ARM using the mandrel images.